# Zero-downtime deployment of Azure Functions with Terraform

Tags: azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an Azure Function App where the necessary cloud infrastructure is scripted by Terraform. The relation to application archive is implemented via `azurerm_storage_blob` and the `app_settings` property `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

```
// ...

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "archive" {
  name                   = "application.zip"
  storage_account_name   = var.storage_account_name
  storage_container_name = var.storage_container_name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "dist/application.zip"
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "app" {
  name                      = "function-app"
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  location                  = var.location
  app_service_plan_id       = var.azurerm_app_service_plan_id
  storage_connection_string = var.storage_connection_string

  app_settings = {
    // ...
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE     = "https://${var.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/${var.storage_container_name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.archive.name}${var.storage_account_sas}"
  }
}

// ...
```

To deploy a new version of the Function App, I taint the `azurerm_storage_blob` and run `terraform apply`. During the execution of the command the Function App isn't avialable for sevaral seconds.

How can I implemented a zero-downtime deployment with Terraform?

---

I found two approaches but couldn't solve the problem.

1. Terraform's `create_before_destroy` shouldn't be working because the `azurerm_function_app` is updated by Terraform.
2. Terraform's `azurerm_app_service_slot` isn't ready for Function Apps ([#1307](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1307), [#4684](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4684))

Comment: What's your meaning of `the Function App isn't available for several seconds`, how did you detect it.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I sent requests using `curl` to URL of the function app, e.g. `"https://${azurerm_function_app.app.default_hostname}/api/hello?code=${lookup(...)}"`

Comment: What is the reason you think it's a problem, not the Network fluctuation? You need to provide more info to display your purpose and the reason.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: the `azurerm_app_service_slot` issues are resolved by [PR#6435](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/6435) and documented by [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app_slot.html) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-slot-swap).  This answer doesn't yet cover that completely.  To avoid deleting and then recreating your blob, change your blob `name` when your code changes and add `HASH` to your `app_settings`:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "archive" {
  name                   = "application.${var.package_version}.zip"
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "app" {
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_function_app_slot" "slotStaging" {
  name                       = "stag"
  function_app_name          = azurerm_function_app.app.name
  ...
  app_settings = {
    ...
    HASH = base64encode(filesha256("dist/application.zip"))
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "swapSlots" {
  triggers = {
    HASH = azurerm_function_app.app.app_settings.HASH
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 1m && az functionapp deployment slot swap -g ${azurerm_resource_group.resourceGroup.name} -n ${azurerm_function_app.functionApp.name} --slot ${azurerm_function_app_slot.slotStaging.name} --target-slot production"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_function_app.functionApp]
}
```

Explanation:
There is a first issue impacting you described at https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1990.  Basically that Terraform wont detect changes to the content of your zip and needs a mechanism to do so.  Making sure the package version name is in the blob name ensure it is updated when a new change happens.  It can be any name change, it just seems more elegant to rely on semver.

So long as your code is updated to the bucket and the HASH of it is part of your function's config (as automatically calculated), then Terraform will know to update the function to reload the new code.  This will happen as a no downtime configuration change such that the previous code version will be invalidated and a new container will be composed and deployed to your host to handle the next request it is ready to catch.

WIP
The default slot is `production`.  Pushing your updated code into the `stag` slot followed by the swapping from `stag` to `production`

The slot is transitioned with `az functionapp deployment slot swap -g MyResourceGroup -n MyUniqueApp --slot staging --target-slot production` which can be run in a `null_resource`.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly in this question, you want to avoid the downtime when you deploy a new version of the Azure function app from a `.zip` file in the storage account with Terraform.

If there is only one attribute `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` that will change in the code when run `terraform apply`, I think the Azure function app will be updated in-place. As a workaround, you could use `ignore_changes` to ignore the websites update first on the first `terraform apply`. Run the next `terraform apply` to update the function app after the tainted `azurerm_storage_blob` has been created.

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"]
    ]
  }
```

Another option, you may create a function app with a new name with a new package. After the new function app provision, you could destroy the old function app. You will use `create_before_destroy = true` for this. It will generate a new function app URL.

You could refer to [this book](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=vDa6DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385&dq=app_settings%20property%20WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE&source=bl&ots=s78YBFdt15&sig=ACfU3U0D64QR5dG_ZrTB2bA11jKfhgWvnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEk5rC6vXmAhWu93MBHaHdB5QQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 385, even it talks to the app service, which has the same deployment logic as the function app.
[image]